# Make Buttons on Tkinter automatically go to next line when reach border of the frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a tkinter script that will print a lot of buttons with functions like this.

```
from tkinter import *

def printbutton(x:int):
   print(x)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
for x in range(1,100):
   Button(root, text = str(x), command = lambda:printbutton(x)).pack(side="left")
root.mainloop()
```

But it print all button in a line and expanded outside of my GUI. I want my button automatically go to the next line for convenient, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Add your Buttons to a Text widget, rather than directly to the window; let the Text's word wrap feature handle the problem.

Comment: @jasonharper can you give me some detail how to do that? I'm new with Tkinter

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest use `grid()` instead of `pack()` for more clarity in such cases.
Next, to pass the value of the button in function, bind your `printbutton(b)` with your button itself. This is because at the end of for loop, the value of x is 99 and this x will be then passed with every button.

Now, to print buttons in a new line after you reach up to the width of the window, I used a simple logic, you can edit the value of `width` variable according to your window and button size.
So, here's what you are looking for:

```
from tkinter import *

def printbutton(btn):
   print(btn["text"])

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

r,c = 0,0
width = 21

for x in range(1,100):
      b = Button(root, text = str(x))
      b.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=N+S+E+W)   #use grid system 
      b["command"] = lambda b=b: printbutton(b) #now b is defined, so add command attribute to b, where you attach your button's scope within a lambda function
                                                #printbutton(b) is the function that passes in the button itself
      c+=1
      if c==width:
          r+=1
          c=0
          
      
root.mainloop()
```